# The best backup tool?

Tags: backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and I was wondering which backup tool is the best at the moment. I do not need some lightweight, but a very robust and powerful tool like I find on windows platforms.

I need to back files periodically to my external hd.

Previously I got an excellent advises here on which app to use for a specific task, so I hope you'll propose another great tool for backup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a software developer and I need to keep my code safe, so I back it up daily.

I have searched lots of back up tools and I have decided that in fact **deja-dup** (Déjà Dup) is the best and easy-to-understand backup tool.

Deja-dup comes by default with Ubuntu 12.04, just search for 'Backup' in the Dash and click on its icon:

[image: deja-dup's icon]

A new window will open which will let you choose your options:
[image: Deja-dup's options]

Deja-dup will silently run, showing only a notification each time the back-up is completed.

It has never destroyed anything, it works like a charm!

Comment: "I am a software developer and I need to keep my code safe" - use systems like git/svn.

Comment: I don't trust them so much :)

Comment: Who is them? You can setup your own servers. (did you mean "those"?)

Comment: @Lekensteyn Even with git you have to push changes, right? In case you forgot, bye bye code ;). Automated backup is much better or usage of cloud services like dropbox.com. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

[Top 5 Open Source Backup Software](http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/12/top-5-open-source-backup-software-for.html). In ubuntu you got [Deja Dup](http://techie-buzz.com/foss/deja-dup-ubuntu-1.html) but in my opinion the must powerful is a [bacula](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Bacula).